# PHP Mailer error using Go Daddy

Tags: php, contact-form

mailPlease help. My PHP mailer is not working that I host on Go Daddy. Any idea why the email won't send?

```
<?php
session_start();

$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$phone=$_POST['telephone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];

$to="webform@xxx.com";
$subject="Contact Form";
$from=$email;
$message .= '<table border="1px" width="50%" style="border:1px black solid;margin:0px auto">';
$message .= '<tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Contacts Information</th></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td>Name :- </td><td>'.$contact.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr> <td>Phone No. :- </td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>';
$message .= "<tr><td>Email :- </td><td>" . $email . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Message :- </td><td>" . $msg. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: sent.html");
```

Comment: What error or issue you are getting ?

Comment: The sent.html page loads but no email is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is a typo error in your code.

```
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$phone=$_POST['telephone'];
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$msg=$_POST['message'];

$to="webform@xxx.com";
 $subject="Contact Form";
$from=$enm; //this should be $from=$email
```

**CAUTION: ur not validating user input. Pls do validate them server side to avoid errors and attack attempts.**

If u have any other error pls state it clearly.

Comment: Thanks - I corrected the typo (and updated the code in the original post). After clicking the submit button, the sent.html page loads, but email is not sent.

Comment: check for ur error log for appropriate error that it gives. I can't help without knowing the error.